# .org,bits AT&T equivalent

Tags: assembly, att

I have code in asm which had intel syntax. I could rewrite it for AT&T syntax.

But now I am stuck with `.org` and `bits` keywords. If I use these directives it throws error.

What are the AT&T equivalent of .org and bits ?
I am using `as` assembler.
intel syntax:

```
.org 100h
bits 16
```

AT&T syntax:
 `??`

I tried searching on internet. But no reference given.

Edit: I got the solution for .org . Now bits remains.

Comment: See [section 9.15.15 Writing 16-bit Code in the binutitls manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002d16bit.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else stuck on this:

Intel `.org 100h` is `.= 0x100` in AT&T syntax and Intel `.bits 16` is equivalent to `.code16`